# Is this a boids bug in 2.75a

Tags: particles

I'm using 2.75a official, and was setting up a particle system using boids. I've used boids before and can recall that whatever boid brain settings (ie... goal, avoid,seperate ect) I added, I was able to adjust the rule fuzzyness setting individually for each rule. This allowed you to kind of put a weighting factor for each rule.

But for some reason now

-I can select a rule, say goal, and assign a rule fuzzyness setting.
-Select the next rule, and change the fuzzyness rule setting to some other setting.

BUT

-that changes the first rule to that second setting.

It seems that it now forces you to use the same fuzzyness rule setting for all rules.

Maybe I am missing something.... but I swear I was able to individually apply different rule fuzzyness settings for each rule.

[image]

Comment: Do you remember in what version this worked this way? It appears to work as it does now even back in 2.69.

Comment: @gandalf3   I really can't remember, but it was a long time ago, but I'm almost positive it did work that way.  Maybe it was a bug that just never got picked up possibly because it doesn't cause crashes.    It definitely helps to be able to adjust this rule fuzzyness to fine tune the animation, but adjusting one, then messes up the others.  I do recognize that order stack of the boid brain items also have a great impact on the animation But it seems strange that the setting is now more of a global setting.

Comment: The tooltip for the "Fuzzy" value in the Rule Evaltuation dropdown says: "Rules are gone through top to bottom (only the first rule which effect is above fuzzines threshold is evaluated)" - so I guess the value you can set above the listbox is this threshold rather than the individual rules' fuzziness. While this does explain why the value is global it does not explain how exactly you control the amount of "effect" that each rule has in this evaluation...